# Will 'Internet Recovery' necessarily erase my hard drive?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, internet-recovery

My Mac is booting to the 'question mark' folder. I option-booted to 'Internet Recovery'. Before I proceed, I would like to know: Will 'Internet Recovery' necessarily erase my hard drive? Can anyone confirm this (maybe even provide a source link)?

Answer (score 4):

No, doing an Internet Recovery *will not* erase your hard drive (unless you explicitly choose do to that using `Disk Utility`). It will only reinstall the OS for you. You should get your drive checked to see if it's just data corruption or a deeper hardware issue that has resulted in the question mark folder icon being shown.

Also, this question has been answered on superuser - see ["Does Internet Recovery erase everything on my Mac?"](https://superuser.com/questions/715991/does-internet-recovery-erase-everything-on-my-mac)