# Apps are not opening in Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, bootcamp, google-chrome

Google Chrome and other apps are not opening, they just bounce and then stop without giving me any error message.

I also re-downloaded Google Chrome and still not opening.

Recently I installed windows 8 via bootcamp and I had to delete lots of useless files I maybe deleted an important file by accident.

Here is a screenshot of the files that won't get deleted from my trash.(possibly important)
[image]

Please help me with this problem. And if it requires terminal I'm fine with it.
I'm running OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.1 MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2012)

Comment: `Won't get deleted from my trash`. Does this mean there were more files, but they were could be deleted? So maybe an important file has been erased already? Can you still open Console.app? It's found in Applications -> Utilities. It shows you all the system (error) messages. If you can open it, do so and watch what it says when you try to open Google Chrome.

Comment: So you deleted a bunch of files from `~/Library` and/or `/Library`? You better get your install disk out/recovery partition warmed up to reinstall the OS then.

Comment: @BartArondson So far all apps by apple works fine, I opened Console the only message I got is "2014-12-20 13:57:16.438 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.google.Chrome.62228[627]) Service exited due to signal: Terminated: 15" I got this message when I forced to quit the app nothing else.

Comment: @deceze How can I do it? and will i lose my data?

Comment: @user3572468 You will lose your data. You took that risk the moment you deleted a `plist` file. `plist` files are essential to the operation of macOS; they're like the registry in Windows. If they go missing, applications don't know how to properly behave. The only option you have is to back up what you have and Factory Reset the whole MacBook

Answer (score 2):

First step: don't delete "useless" files.

If the first step was not done properly, please continue to the second step.

Second step: Perform a [recovery](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4718).
This will restore the OS to its original state but will [leave your user data intact](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/123161/24324).